# Windows or Windows Installer Not Updating Program Icon on Application Search

Tags: windows, wix, icons, windows-installer, installation

I'm using wix (3.11) to create a msi installation for a WPF application. The application icon is correctly working on program launch, in the program list (apps and features), and in my program menu and desktop shortcuts. The only issue is that when I search for the application after pressing the windows key, the older, stale icon that I used a few weeks ago appears. I'm almost certain that this is some windows caching issue as I have removed the stale icon from the application altogether, rebuilt the installer and reinstalled, and still the old icon appears during search. I'm curious if other members have encountered this issue and what they did to remedy it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need to [rebuild the icon cache](https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting) or [fix indexing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366038/correct-way-to-create-shortcuts-in-user-start-menu-csidl-startmenu).

For Indexing:

1. Type "***indexing***" in the start menu (or internationalized equivalent word), Click open.
2. Click the Advanced button.
3. In the **Index Settings tab**, click the **Rebuild button** under Troubleshooting. OK to confirm.

Index rebuilding should start. This Indexing applet is also available from the old-style control panel in "icons" view. Just search for "control panel" or equivalent internationalized words.

---

- One liner code (one effective line and boiler) to refresh icons: https://github.com/crazy-max/IconsRefresh

Comment: Here is a PowerShell one-liner to refresh icons (calls the same function, but runs out-of-the-box): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818826/7571258

Comment: Nice. I keep meaning to look at PowerShell. Too high line-noise for my taste, and too "Perl-like" syntax (cryptic), but powerful for sure.

Comment: I just got a little bit deeper into PowerShell. Yes, one can write cryptic Perl-like one-liners, but that's not forced on you by the language. One can also split a statement by using intermediate variables and make the code more readable by using the full form of commands, instead of the abbreviated ones. This is my preferred style for production scripts. The short, cryptic forms come in handy for quick testing and prototyping though.

Comment: Time to dig out Kopczynski's PowerShell book that is sitting in my book shelf :-). Thanks for the summary. I find operators to be the strangest part of PowerShell.