# Windows start menu icon size for .NET application

Tags: .net, wix, shortcut-file

I'm trying to finalise the setup for my application and there is one thing that is bugging me that I don't understand:  when I search for the application in the start menu, the icon is shrunk and has a border.

[image: windows search result]

The icon I'm using has all the needed size (16, 24, 32, 48, 64, 96, 256). I'm making the setup with the wix toolset.

I've made some tests and I can't figure out where Windows fetches this icon. I've opened the application exe file in resource hacker and all the icon sizes are present. I opened the start menu shortcut of my application in an hex editor and found out that it use an icon from "C:\Windows\Installer{APP_GUID}" but this icon also have all the correct sizes. Even if I change the icon of the shortcut in the start menu folder for a different icon altogether, the start menu result still show the original.

I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Is this an issue with .NET applications or a limitation of the wix toolset?

I know it is only a minor aesthetic issue but it really drives me crazy.

Comment: The icon in the Installer folder is put there by an MSI installer. With regards to the actual problem I am not sure what causes it I am afraid. Did you try to [rebuild the icon cache and reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263035/129130) - just for debugging? Some say you should delete the **`IconCache.db`** file under `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local`.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I did try to rebuild the icon cache but I did not reboot, I will try that. Also Windows seems to be shrinking the 32x32 icon instead of using the 16x16 (I can tell because I designed the icon differently for the 16x16)